# Query func does not return error on chdb lib chdb-go

Tags: go, clickhouse

i am using chdb-go library
When creating a database or table, it does not return an error if it already exists, but it prints a debug on the terminal.
the example code:

```
db, err := chdb.NewSession("a") //path is option
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("hata", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Print("\nburası\n")

    a := db.Query("CREATE DATABASE db")
    fmt.Println("a değeri",a)

    db.Query("USE db")
```

the terminal:

```
burası
Code: 82. DB::Exception: Database db already exists. (DATABASE_ALREADY_EXISTS)
a değeri
```

Does anyone have any solution suggestions?
Thank you, happy new year
And also tried this for python use try cath but it's not working too